# Measure the precise execution time of each thread

Tags: java

I have a challenge which I could not figure it out. This is the scenario. I want to do special task in every one second. It's simple at the first glance but the point is if for instance the first thread which was running one second age could not be done at the one second for example takes more that one second, the second thread must be started exactly after one second and this should be done for the rest threads respectively.

I try to use ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean() and its methods such as getThreadUserTime or getThreadCpuTime but none of them worked. Now I am wondering is it really possible to handle this challenge or not? Is there ant possible way to get the real execution time of each thread in Java?

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand why the title has to do with the requirements. If I understand correctly you want to start several tasks with exactly one second delay between each *start*. In other words: when a given task is done is immaterial for your goal, just that they are run with exactly one second delay.

Comment: Yes exactly. The thing that is important for me is the duration time between each one.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting there are no guarantees that a new process will run every 1 second. If jobs are taking longer than 1 second to complete, then there will eventually be some back-up. If this happens, some ways of handling it are:

1. See if there are performance improvements which can be done.
2. Add more resources to the machine.
3. Add to a queue for reprocessing at a later date.
4. Throw an Exception.

Assuming some backup is acceptable, one way to approach this is to have a thread pool handling work and a manager thread which starts new jobs every 1 second. Something like this may work:

```
    private static final Duration sleep = ofSeconds(1);
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            executor.submit(new Process());
            Thread.sleep(sleep.toMillis());
        }
    }

    public static final class Process implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt((int) sleep.toMillis()));
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("Stopped"); return; }
        }
    }
```

If the same process is being scheduled, Java ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate can handle process scheduling for you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

```
    private static final Duration sleep = ofSeconds(1);
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Process(), sleep.toMillis(), sleep.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(Duration.ofMinutes(1).toMillis());
    }

    public static final class Process implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt((int) sleep.toMillis()));
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("Stopped"); return; }
        }
    }
```